# Generate IPA from Xcode 6

Tags: ios, code-signing-certificate

I have two macbook machine.
I have same app on both.
I have created certificates, provisioning profile for first macbook and now i am able to generate IPA. using these details can i generate IPA from my second macbook?

please help me for generate IPA from my second macbook.

Appreciate for help

Comment: just get the certificate to the 2nd machine, and just sync your account in Xcode . thats it .. just start export via archive it

Comment: @KumarKL please explain in detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to keyChain , select those certificates , right click on them , select export option (keep file format .p12)  save it , and email them to the urself ,
now open your email in another macbook , install those certificates on another mac

now , the way you have created IPA in first mac , u can do for another one .